# Identifying the calling python script in the called python script and print

Tags: python

How can I print the name of the script that called the current script in python? Are there any built-in functions to identify the source script?

Example: if `x.py` calls `y.py` and `y.py` calls `z.py`, I want to print `x.py` in `z.py` as `x.py` initiated the function.

Comment: Take a tour of the [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module -- lots of fun tidbits in there!